# Get Azure subscription through name - python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to get the specific subscription given a subscription name?

I only want to get the specific subscription by querying it using the name. So far I have only seen retrieval using subscription ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the specific subscription given a subscription
> name?

Using [`Subscriptions - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/get) REST API, it is not possible to do so as it expects Subscription Id.

What you can do however is list all subscriptions that you have access to using [`Subscriptions - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list) and then filter the result by `displayName` property (which is the name of the subscription).